# Get whole line where Regex matches

Tags: c#, regex

I have some multiline text and I want to find the lines that contain a specific word.

In the current implementation I only get the word, but instead I would like to get the whole line. Here's the code:

```
var finder = new Regex(@"(^|\W)" + Regex.Escape(wordToFind) + @"(\W|$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
 foreach (var match in finder.Matches(multilineString))
 {
      //match should be the whole line
 }
```

Example:

```
If Request.QueryString("bar") <> "" Then
    Set bar= foo("baz")
Else
    Set bar= foo("baz2")
End If
```

If I look for `foo` I should get:

```
Set bar= foo("baz")
Set bar= foo("baz2")
```

I didn't implement the regex and I'm not very familiar with Regular Expressions, I would appreciate if someone could give me some hints to keep investigating.

Thanks

Comment: Add .* ... .*\n somewhere in your regex.

Comment: Maybe try `@"^.*?" + Regex.Escape(wordToFind) + @".*?$"`? `^` matches the start of the string or line, `.*?` matches everything (but only as much as necessary), `$` matches the end of string or line.

Comment: @Nolonar what is the point of your `?`

Comment: @mathk Without the `?`, the `.*` will match as much as possible, so my regex without `?` will match the entire string if the word is found, not just the line it is found on.

Comment: Show some sample input and expected output

Comment: Do you have to do this with a regex ?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use Regex

Comment: @Nolonar I still don't see the utility of it. `^.*foo.*$` match only if it contain the word foo. Regex engine should know how to backtrack properly.

Comment: @mathk It's not about *when* it matches, but *what* it matches. Assuming you have a string `"hello\nthis foo is\nworld"`, the regex `^.*foo.*$` will match `"hello\nthis foo is\nworld"`; the regex `^.*?foo.*?$` will instead match only `"this foo is"`. Yes, they both match *only* if `foo` is found, but they don't match the same thing.

Comment: @Nolonar nop it still match the whole string. Try it there: http://regexhero.net/tester/. You need more stuff in your regex something like `^.*\n(.*foo.*?\n).*$`

Comment: @Nolonar Your solution is almost working. The only problem is that if for example I look for "validate" and there's a "validateXML" it matches. It should only match the word.

Comment: I got this one: `^(.*?)(\foo\b)(.*)$`. It seems to work!

Comment: @margabit Then you should add `\W` before and after `wordToFind`. It matches any non-word character (character that is neither a letter or a number), so it'd match "validate-XML" but not "validateXML". Notice the *W* is uppercase, **not** lowercase!

Comment: @Nolonar Awesome! You should write an answer so I can mark it as accepted!

Comment: @margabit Done, I hope my answer covers your regex needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^.*?\W" + Regex.Escape(wordToFind) + @"\W.*?$");
```

The `^` matches the start of the string or line, the `$` at the end matches the end of string or line.
The `.*?` matches everything (but as little as possible), and `\W` (uppercase "W") matches any non-word character (characters that are neither a letter nor a digit).

Alternatively you can use `\s` (lowercase "s") instead of `\W` if you want your words to be separated by whitespaces only.

[Here is a good reference for Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx).

Comment: This worked for me `.*ERROR.*` Here I am capturing entire line where the word ERROR is present

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
string[] lines = multilinestring.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
List<string> validString = new List<string>();
foreach(string s in lines)
{
   if(finder.Match(s).Success)
   {
      validString.Add(s);
   }
}
```

give this a try as well, should work

```
List<string> lines = multilinestring.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
List<string> validString =  lines.Where(x => finder.IsMatch(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: Sorry, I would need a Regex for that. I tested my code and works, but it's 2 times slower than with a Regex.

Answer (score 0):

[Nolonar's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386760/3832970) [does not take into account](https://regex101.com/r/r1h73N/1) the possibility when a line starts or ends with a required word.

Moreover, you need to remember that `^` and `$` anchors match the start/end of the whole *string* unless you pass the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option to make them match *line* boundaries.

Hence, the correct regex-only solution to **extract all lines containing a whole word** is

```
var finder = new Regex($@"^.*?(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(wordToFind)}(?!\w).*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
// Or, in order to avoid getting CR at the end of the extracted lines
// var finder = new Regex($@"^.*?(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(wordToFind)}(?!\w)[^\r\n]*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var results = finder.Matches(multilineString).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value); // Use x.Value.Trim() to trim the result
```

Note you may "shrink" the code a bit by incorporating `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline` into the pattern itself using *inline modifiers*, `(?im)`:

```
var finder = new Regex($@"(?im)^.*?(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(wordToFind)}(?!\w).*");
var finder = new Regex($@"(?im)^.*?(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(wordToFind)}(?!\w)[^\r\n]*"); 
                          ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fim%29%5E.*%3F%28%3F%3C!%5Cw%29foo%28%3F!%5Cw%29.*&i=foo%20here%20%0D%0AIf%20Request.QueryString%28%22bar%22%29%20%3C%3E%20%22%22%20Then%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Set%20bar%3D%20foo%28%22baz%22%29%0D%0AElse%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Set%20bar%3D%20foo%28%22baz2%22%29%0D%0AEnd%20If%0D%0Aand%20another%20foo)

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of a line
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than a newline char, as few as possible (`*?` is a lazy, non-greedy quantifier)
- `(?<!\w)` - the left-hand side word boundary
- `{Regex.Escape(wordToFind)}` - an escaped version of a `wordToFind` string
- `(?!\w)` - the right-hand side word boundary
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than a newline char, as many as possible (`*` is a greedy quantifier). **NOTE**: `.` matches a carriage return, `\r`, in .NET regex, hence my suggestion to `.Trim()` the extracted values. Or use `[^\r\n]*` instead to match 0 or more chars other than CR and LF.